# Java: minimum number of operations for conjunctive inequalities?

Tags: java, math, for-loop, conditional-statements, predicate

I try to simplify conditionals in:

```
for ( int t=0, size=fo.getPrintViewsPerFile().size();
          t<size && t<countPerFile;
          t++)
{
    // ...
}
```

, more precisely:

```
t<s && t<c
```

You need to compare two times, then calc the boolean value from them. Is there any simpler way to do it? If no, how can you prove it? I can simplify it to some extent, [proof tree.](http://www.umsu.de/logik/trees/?f=(%5Cexists%20s%20%5Cexists%20c%20%5Cforall%20t%20%20(Pts%20%5Cland%20Ptc))%5Cleftrightarrow%5Cneg(%5Cforalls%5Cforallc%5Cexistst(%5Cneg(Pts)%5Clor%5Cneg(Ptc))))

**[Added]**

I tried to solve the problem directly through logic. It would interesting to see the implication in choosing the minima. Link:

http://www.umsu.de/logik/trees/?f=(\exists%20s%20\exists%20c%20\forall%20t%20%20(Pts%20\land%20Ptc))\leftrightarrow\neg(\foralls\forallc\existst(\neg(Pts)\lor\neg(Ptc)))

Comment: Exactly the same question was asked a week or two ago. Regularly, actually. I just can't find it :) The answer at least boils down to "no, live with it". There are ways to make it shorter/different, but not faster.

Comment: @HH: that formula you proved are simply quantified De Morgan's Laws (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Comment: BalusC: There is certain Repetitivenes noticed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316084/why-is-my-loop-skipping-this-conditional/2316140#2316140. Clearly, some things are timeless :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `t < Math.min(s, c)`, but that wouldn't actually reduce the number of comparison.

I do think that appropriate use of [`Math.min`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min%28int,%20int%29) and `Math.max` makes for a much more readable code, though. Unfortunately they only have overloads for 2 args (for `int`, `long`, `float` and `double` arguments). It would've been really nice if they also have 3 args and varargs overloads.

You can always write utilities method for these kinds of things (interval checking is a common idiom `(minV <= v) && (v <= maxV)` etc), but *linguistically*, no Java doesn't have any fancy operators that would do these things. They only have basic numerical comparison operators ([JLS 15.20.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.20.1)) and basic boolean operators ([JLS 15.22.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.22.2), [15.23](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.23), [15.24](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.24)).

---

#### Sidenote

Higher-level languages like [Icon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icon_%28programming_language%29) *does* allow these kinds of constructs:

```
Java                      Icon
(x < v1) || (x < v2)      x < (v1 | v2)
(a < b) && (b < c)        a < b < c
```

Comment: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html -- basically you can give it any number of arguments, and you can also find the min/max of an array by just passing the entire array. Would've been quite useful.

Answer (score 3):

If `size` and `countPerFile` are constant for the duration of the loop, you can precalculate their minimum before the loop, and then the test would be `t<minimum`.

```
int size=fo.getPrintViewsPerFile().size();
int minLimit = Math.min(size, countPerFile);
for (int t=0; t<minLimit; t++) {
    ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Forget about it. If you're dealing with printing or files this kind of micro-optimizaton would save you practically nothing.